# How to set preference Debug to run first before Release in vNext TFS Builds?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, tfsbuild, vnext

I have TFS vNext build setup but when I run with Multiconfiguration option I want Debug mode to run first and then Release mode. However, I change the settings it always runs Release mode first.

[Release Mode runs first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxQCY.png)

[Multiconfig settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q29tt.png)

Comment: Can you explain why the order matters? It's going to be two unrelated builds regardless of the order they run in.

Comment: I have a lot of .csproj pointing to x64/obj/Debug as path references which indeed needs the solutions to get built in Debug mode and then Release mode to have the required DLLs already IN there.

Comment: Then I guarantee you that what you're trying to do **will not work**. Each build runs in a separate location that has outputs cleaned prior to running. Your projects should build everything needed or use some sort of versioned package mechanism like NuGet to share binary dependencies.

Comment: I agree with that. I have a few NuGet package created and consuming from that. But for these its a lot of work eventually I have to move everything to NuGet.

Addtionally I was able to figure out and now all my builds run as Debug mode first and Release mode second. I changed the order of $(BuildConfiguration) variable to Debug,Release and it works fine for me now.